# how do you figure out the digit for radix sort

Tags: java, radix-sort

Hi all i need to write a RADIX sorting algorithm for an arbitrary amount of digits and values. I figured it would be easier to use LL to manipulate rather than Arrays for storing the 0-9 values. I think it would be better to use recursion to solve this problem but im having difficulty and getting errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.LinkedList$Node.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedList.linkLast(Unknown Source)
at java.util.LinkedList.add(Unknown Source)
```

i would really appreciate any guidance! :)

```
            import java.util.LinkedList;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class pt2 {
            long[] mine;
            int digits;
            Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
            public pt2() {
                makeArray();
                add();
                RADIX(mine,1);
            }

                @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    void RADIX(int[] kiki, int digi){
    while(digi<=digits){
        LinkedList<Integer> l0 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l3 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l4 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l5 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l6 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l7 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l8 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> l9 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList[] cap ={l0,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9};

        for( int j=0;j<kiki.length;j++){
            int k=0;
            while(k<10){
                //need to put the number in the correct LL but how
                int jk = digital(kiki[j],(int)(Math.pow(10,digi)));
                if(jk==k){
                    cap[k].add(kiki[j]);
                    k=11;
                }
                k++;
            }
        }       
        int i = 0;
        while(i<kiki.length){
            int p=0;
            while(p<10){
                while(cap[p].isEmpty()==false){
                    kiki[i]=(int) cap[p].removeFirst();

                }
                p++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        digi++;
    }
}
public int digital(int num, int pos){
    int i = (int) (num % Math.pow(10,pos));
    i= (int)(i/Math.pow(10, pos-1));
    return i;
}

            void add(){
                int i=0;
                while(i<mine.length){
                    mine[i] = (long)(Math.random()*digits);
                    i++;
                }
            }

            void makeArray(){
                System.out.println("Max size?");
                mine = new long[sn.nextInt()];
                System.out.println("Max digits?);
                if(digits<0){
                    System.out.println("bad USer");
                }else{

                    digits = sn.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
```

now this returns

Max size?
10
Max digits?
2
Not Sorted

### 74 63 87 52 1 99 10 74 67 49

Sorted
49 63 87 52 1 99 10 74 67 49 End

Answer (score 0):

Store your linked lists in another List or an array instead of having 10 separate variables.  Then you can have the digit be the index or offset to choose the right one.

Comment: i do store them in a LinkedList[] cap.